# LISP: with predicate as parameter

Tags: function, parameters, lisp, common-lisp, predicate

I want a predicate as a parameter of a function.

```
(DEFUN per (F L)
    (cond ((F L) 'working)
          (T     'anything)))

(per 'numberp 3)
```

as result it raises an error:

> Undefined operator F in form (F L).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in [Technical Issues of Separation in Function Cells and Value Cells](http://www.nhplace.com/kent/Papers/Technical-Issues.html),
Common Lisp is a Lisp-2, i.e., you
need [`funcall`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_funcal.htm):

```
(defun per (F L)
  (if (funcall F L)
      'working
      'other))
(per #'numberp 3)
==> WORKING
(per #'numberp "3")
==> OTHER
```

See also [`apply`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_apply.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but here's another example:

```
(defun strip-predicate (p list)
    (cond ((endp list) nil)
        ((funcall p (first list)) (strip-predicate (rest list)))
        ( T (cons (first list) (strip-Predicate p (rest list))))))
```

This could be used on predicates such as atom or numberp:

```
(strip-predicate 'numberp '(a 1 b 2 c 3 d))
```

> (a b c d)

or:

```
(strip-predicate 'atom '(a (a b) b c d))
```

> ((a b))